# use of deleted function 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)'

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have class eventEngine and gateway like below:

```
class eventEngine
{
public:
    eventEngine(); 

    std::thread threa;
    std::thread timer;  
};

class Gateway 
{
protected:
    eventEngine ee;
    std::string gatewayName;
};
```

constructor for gateway:

```
Gateway::Gateway(eventEngine ee, std::string gatewayName)
{ 

this->ee.threa = std::move(ee.threa);
this->ee.timer = std::move(ee.timer);

this->gatewayName = gatewayName;
}
```

and main1.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    eventEngine e;
    std::string names = "abc";
    Gateway g(e,names);

    return 0;
}
```

when I try to compile in main1.cpp, i get error:

```
main1.cpp:12:21: error: use of deleted function 'eventEngine::eventEngine(const eventEngine&)'
  Gateway g(e,names);
                     ^
In file included from Gateway.h:11:0,
                 from main1.cpp:2:
eventEngine.h:25:7: note: 'eventEngine::eventEngine(const eventEngine&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class eventEngine
       ^
eventEngine.h:25:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)'
In file included from Gateway.h:8:0,
                 from main1.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include/c++/thread:126:5: note: declared here
     thread(const thread&) = delete;
     ^
In file included from Gateway.h:11:0,
                 from main1.cpp:2:
eventEngine.h:25:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)'
 class eventEngine
```

I have searched similar problems, it looks like there are problems with std::thread, thread is non-copy class, I have changed to std::move as in this->ee.threa = std::move(ee.threa);
this->ee.timer = std::move(ee.timer);
but it still gives me error, what is the problem here?

Comment: The constructor for `Gateway` takes an  `eventEngine` by value (tries to copy it).  `eventEngine` contains an `std::thread`; `std::thread` can not be copied.

Comment: `eventEngine ee` - that's a *by-value* copy of the engine from `main`. You can't copy `std::thread`, and since `eventEngine` has `std::thread` instance members, you cannot use default copy-construction or copy-assignmen on `eventEngine`s either. You *can* provide your own overrides, but I doubt that is your desired goal. Pass your ctor-params by reference.

Comment: The model that the `std::thread` class provides is that its instances represent *actual resources*, not just a *reference* to an actual resource. Consequently, as you've written the `eventEngine` class, it too represents *actual resources*. As its written, you have the wrong semantics of its use in your head -- you shouldn't think that it makes sense to copy an `eventEngine` instance, or to pass it by value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make this work, you should change your code:

```
Gateway::Gateway(eventEngine&& ee, std::string&& gatewayName)
{
    this->ee = std::move(ee);    
    this->gatewayName = std::move(gatewayName);
}
```

and

```
Gateway g(std::move(e), std::move(names));
```

or simply

```
Gateway g(eventEngine{}, "abc");
```

---

But the best way is to write in standard form:

```
Gateway::Gateway(eventEngine&& ee, std::string&& gatewayName) : ee{std::move(ee)}, gatewayName{std::move(gatewayName)} {}
```

---

Your code doesn't work because you try to init function argument with copy-ctor, which is deleted due to deleted `std::thread`'s and respectively `eventEngine`'s copy-ctors. You should use move-ctors instead of them.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, why the clumsy `this->ee = std::move(ee);` statement instead of a simple initializer: `ee{std::move(ee)}`?